# Delphi: load file into TStringGrid

Tags: delphi, logging, tstringgrid

There is a program that creates a log file.

This is an example of the log file it creates:

[image]

This program loads this log file into a TStringGrid. The log file is tab delimited. A cell can has a space " ".

How can I use TStringGrid or an alternative to load such a log file into it like this program?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This procedure loads the log into a string list. For each line in the log, it assigns the [CommaText](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Classes.TStrings.CommaText) property of the corresponding row in the grid control. That property automatically splits comma- and space-separated tokens in a string. If you have a newer Delphi version, you can use the [DelimitedText](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Classes.TStrings.DelimitedText) property instead, which will be more appropriate if the log might ever contain unquoted commas.

```
procedure LoadLogFile(const FileName: TFileName; Grid: TStringGrid);
var
  LogFile: TStrings;
  i: Integer;
begin
  LogFile := TStringList.Create;
  try
    LogFile.LoadFromFile(FileName);
    Grid.RowCount := LogFile.Count;
    for i := 0 to Pred(LogFile.Count) do
      Grid.Rows[i].CommaText := LogFile[i];
  finally
    LogFile.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Good! One thing - it can be a space in a cell. The code cannot fill rows. I have Delphi 2010.

Comment: Please see the exact picture :)

Comment: @maxfax, if that picture is a picture of a text editor, your text columns are either tab separated or fixed width. If they're tab separated, do `Grid.Rows[i].Delimiter := #9` followed by `Gird.Rows[i].StrictDelimiter := True` and then use `Grid.Rows[i].DelimitedText`, not `Grid.Rows[i].CommaText`. This is assuming the `Grid.Rows[i]` is actually a `TStrings`, I didn't check that.

Comment: Thanks!!! I had used all you has sad except Gird.Rows[i].StrictDelimiter := True :)

Comment: @maxfax, if Not(EnglishGrammarGood) then try AlwaysUseHave except end; :-)